# How to manage request and response in JSON format using spring 3

Tags: json, spring, web-services

I have to write a logic where I would be receiving JSON request and I have to return response in JSON format. I am using spring 3 and would be using restful controller in spring MVC using @responseBody annotation.
Please tell me what should be my approach with sample code and how can I test it without any front end available in best manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json format is nothing but a string. You can use rest template for getting ur result. You have to set message converter bean in your context xml.
pls go through the link below

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program